# Duplicate symbol in Clang (but not GCC) when overriding __cxa_throw

Tags: c++, clang, abi

I'm trying to get a bit more information in __cxa_throw. Regardless of the wisdom of this, the following code works perfectly with gcc and from the limited information I can find about this, it should work <strike>its perfectly legal even if there are some caveats</strike>. Please note I'm only planning this for debug builds. Clang is giving

```
ld.lld: error: duplicate symbol: __cxa_throw
>>> defined at exc_override.cpp
>>>            exc.o:(__cxa_throw)
>>> defined at cxa_exception.cpp
>>>            cxa_exception.cpp.o:(.text.__cxa_throw+0x0) in archive /opt/compilers/clang-12.0.1/bin/../lib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/c++/libc++.a
```

`main.cxx`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "exc_override.h"

int main(int argc, char** argn) {

    try {
        throw std::runtime_error("boom");
    } catch(...)
    {
        std::cout << "caught" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`exc_override.h`

```
#pragma once

extern "C"
void __cxa_throw (void *thrown_exception, void *pvtinfo, void (*dest)(void *)) ;
```

`exc_override.cpp`

```
#include "exc_override.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include "stdio.h"

typedef void (*cxa_throw_type)(void *, void *, void (*) (void *));
cxa_throw_type orig_cxa_throw = 0;

void load_orig_throw_code()
{
    orig_cxa_throw = (cxa_throw_type) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "__cxa_throw");
}

extern "C"
void __cxa_throw (void *thrown_exception, void *pvtinfo, void (*dest)(void *)) {
    printf(" ################ DETECT A THROWN !!!!! #############\n");
    if (orig_cxa_throw == 0)
        load_orig_throw_code();
    
    {}
    orig_cxa_throw(thrown_exception, pvtinfo, dest);
}
```

and I'm building it in gcc (4.8.5) with the following commands

```
gcc main.o exc_override.o -o testprogram
g++ main.o exc_override.o -o testprogram
g++ main.o exc_override.o -o testprogram -ldl >
```

In Clang 12.0.1

```
clang++ -c main.cxx -o main.o
clang++ -c exc_override.cpp -o exc.o
clang++ main.o exc.o -o testprogram
```

Comment: `__cxa_throw` is a reserved name and you may not define it in your code. See [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: Are clang and gcc using the same libraries and linker?

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm unfamiliar with the clang toolchain. I believe using clang++ will use the lld linker though.

Comment: @273K I've seen articles (granted only a few) and at least one opensource DB override this successfully and it works in the gcc toolchain

Comment: You have seen some hacks, As said above, the name is reserved, its ABI is not documented or even guaranteed, and a user app cannot use it. [libcxxabi/include/cxxabi.h:48](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxxabi/blob/ce3db128f9e4d6d19d1cdbe39bb45fcc64a5adb0/include/cxxabi.h#L48) - is not a weak symbol in LLVM libc++.

Comment: It does not matter if it "might" work for some people with some code-source and some compiler: using double-underscore in your name IS undefined behaviour. That's it. As soon as you try it the compiler is free to ignore your code and order 2890345 melon-sandwiches

Comment: _Regardless of the wisdom of this_ - I think that's fair enough.  OP is trying to get some additional logging info, if it breaks at any point not much is lost.  Just don't do it in a release build.

Comment: @PaulSanders I was planning on this being for debug builds only

Comment: @Steve did you have a question?

Comment: *"it should work"* -- More precisely, it should work for certain versions of gcc. A reserved name can mean different things for different C++ toolchains. A use that works for one compiler might very well fail for another, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77553278).

Comment: @JaMiT I see what you did there... :)

Comment: Debate aside, is your question why it doesn't work on clang or how to make something equivalent to this work with clang? (Or something else -- I don't see a question mark to help me see what you are asking.)

Comment: @JaMiT @ Super-intelligent Shade yes, sorry I thought the question was implied. But "how do I make this work in Clang" was the question. If it only works in GCC for my debug builds that's fine also

Comment: @273k's second comment explains why it's unlikely that clang will allow this.